# How to send images(files of size > 128KB) from device using aws-iot

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Since aws IoT supports 128KB as a default message size , how can a device using nodejs sdk to connect to aws-iot can send images or files of size > 128KB.

Comment: Can you break the file into multiple pieces and send across messages and re-assemble on the other side?  Can you store in s3, and send a message for the device to pull the image from s3?

Comment: Yeah storing in s3  looks ok , but i have to upload image into s3 from device (its like a camera sensor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setup a simple web service in front of s3 to get the pieces and push them to s3.. you can use a Lambda function fronted by the API system.. if you're getting regular input, it should be relatively light...

Alternatively you can host a webservice on Digital Ocean, Linode or another service and push the data into s3 (or azure blob storage)... either should work for you.

Comment: Then how to send same images to greengrass core over MQTT when image should remain on the edge to fulfill data compliance?